# How to remove panGesture after touch in swift

Tags: swift, uigesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer

I have a view that recognizes both a UIPanGesture and a single tap. How do I disable the pan gesture once the view has been tapped? I have tried multiple ways but cannot seem to figure it out. Here is the last method I tried:

```
 func gestureRecognizer(singleTapRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer?, shouldRequireFailureOfGestureRecognizer panGesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer?) -> Bool? {
    print("in gesture recognizer")
    if wasTapped == true {
        return true
    }
    else {
        return false

    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: i mean you could disable it  or set it to false **gestureRecognizer.enabled = false**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for something along the lines of

```
panGesture.requireGestureRecognizerToFail(singleTapRecognizer)
```

Which would, preferably, be called just after you have created both of the gesture recognizers.

Comment: Thanks!! I had tried that before but I had to declare variables as the gestures before manipulating them. It works now!